# get SVG path if doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I'm trying to learn svg to do something like that : https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/ but with text SVG.

I make this to have a SVG `Hello` :

```html
<svg id="SVGHello">
    <text x="0" y="40vh">Hello</text>
</svg>
```

but I don't have any `path` part in my html, so I can't make something like that :

```js
var path = document.querySelector('.path');
var length = path.getTotalLength();
```

There is an other solution to get the path length?

Comment: where is your `getTotalLength();` function?

Comment: @dgknca It's https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGPathElement/getTotalLength

Answer (score 1):

You must have a shape element (usually a `<path>`) in order to use that line animation effect.

To create the path, use a vector editor, add your text, and then convert it to a path.

Almost any vector editor should work.  There are free ones you can use, such as Inkscape.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a path for your text for it to work. And after defining it you should link the text to the path.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice" viewBox="0 0 728 400">
<defs>
  <path id="path" 
    d="M 10,30
       A 20,20 0,0,1 50,30
       A 20,20 0,0,1 90,30
       Q 90,60 50,90
       Q 10,60 10,30 z" />
</defs>
<text font-family="monospace" font-size="20" fill="#1d1f20">
  <textPath id="text" xlink:href="#path">Hello</textPath>
</text>
</svg>
```

Also, regarding the link you shared, it says that the path should have a `stroke`. I suggest you to have a look at this [codepen](https://codepen.io/VisualAngle/pen/mzKKZW).

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't get an attribute of an element which doesn't exist.